# JSP not opening -Javascript validator checked

Tags: eclipse

When I try to open a jsp in Eclipse, it seems to hang. I think this is because Javascript Validators are checked
I am trying to  uncheck the Javascript validators under the Builder property.That property is grayed out. So when I try to uncheck it, eclipse hangs.
Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JavaScript Validation *Builder* only affects .js files.  Web pages are handled by the JavaScript *Validator* from the **Validation** property/preference page.

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/How_to_report_a_deadlock for how to find out whether the JavaScript Validator is even involved (my guess would be that it is not).